# How to get full drop-down object item using Reactive Forms?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, visual-studio-code, angular-material

In this case I'm not using ngModel directives.
I want to know how to get the full object binded to the drop down when it change.

Basically, this is what I'm doing:

> It's an array of objects with properties, but i don't want only the
>   value, i want the full object selected

```
<select #tipoTextoItem (change)="handleChange($item)" name="cmbTipoTexto" class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-7" id="cmbTipoTexto" formControlName="cmbTipoTexto">
    <option *ngFor="let item of textTypes" value="{{item.key}} {{item.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Then...

```
handleChange($event) {
    console.log($event.ForExampleGetMyObjectInThisWay());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use compareWith input property provided by angular. In the function you can compare and return the object. You can use it like:-

```
<select #tipoTextoItem (change)="handleChange($item)"
                        [compareWith]="compareFn"
                        name="cmbTipoTexto"
                        class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-7" 
                        id="cmbTipoTexto"
                        formControlName="cmbTipoTexto">
                        <option *ngFor="let item of textTypes" 
                                value="{{item}}">{{item.value}}</option>
                </select>
```

In your component.ts file,

```
compareFn(item1, item2) {
return item1 && item2 ? item1.value === item2.value : item1 === item1;
}
```

You can look into below link for more info:-
https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection

Answer (score 0):

you can use `selectedIndex`, Here you go :

```
(change)="handleChange($event.target.selectedIndex)" // change method

handleChange(index) {
    console.log(this.textTypes[index]);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-get-selected-object)**